# job can't be submitted inside sge file

Tags: linux, server, cluster-computing, sungridengine

I want to submit a sge job via sge file.

For example, I have ***run.sge*** file as follows:

```
## SGE options
#$ -cwd
#$ -l mem_free=2G
##$ -q all.q@compute-2-3.local
#$ -pe mpich 4
#$ -S /bin/bash

SCRATCH_DIR=/state/partition1/$USER-$JOB_ID
mkdir $SCRATCH_DIR

qsub run_inp.sge

rmdir $SCRATCH_DIR
```

And ***run_inp.sge*** file as follows:

```
## SGE options
#$ -cwd
#$ -l mem_free=2G
##$ -q all.q@compute-2-3.local
#$ -pe mpich 4
#$ -S /bin/bash

INPUTFILE="main.inp"
JOB="main"

SCRATCH_DIR=/state/partition1/$USER-$JOB_ID
mkdir $SCRATCH_DIR

/share/apps/simula/Commands/abaqus double inp=$INPUTFILE scratch=$SCRATCH_DIR job=$JOB mp_mode=mpi interactive

rmdir $SCRATCH_DIR
```

Whenever I submit job via

```
qsub run.sge
```

I got this error:

```
Unable to run job: denied: host "compute-2-9.local" is no submit host.
Exiting.
```

But if I submit run_inp.sge directly, it works fine:

```
qsub run_inp.sge
```

My question is that can I submit sge jobs inside a sge job? If not, is there alternative way to do such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal approach is to submit all jobs from one host where you login, submit your jobs, and check job status.  The submitted jobs are scheduled to execute on compute nodes in the cluster.  If you have multiple jobs and dependencies between the jobs, you can declare the dependencies to the job scheduler. For example, you can tell the scheduler to wait for job A to finish before starting job B.

Answer (score 1):

The node which the first job (**run.sge**) gets submitted to, `compute-2-9.local`, must also be a submit node as you call `qsub` again in **run_inp.sge**. The `qsub` command is permitted only on a submit node. Currently `compute-2-9.local` is an execution node only, hence the error.  However, as @Steve mentions, better to use job dependencies for this, unless you are trying "incept" SGE!